# Assistance needed with Powershell script to pull email addresses for AD Groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of AD Groups that have an email address associated with them in the LDAP "Mail" attribute.  These groups are used to enable membership for Exchange distrubution groups.

We are in the process of auditing the group names and email addresses and need to pull a list of email addresses for a known list of AD groups.  The group list is in .txt format and consists of one group name per line separated with a carriage return.

I'm attempting to use the following script:

```
Get-Content 'C:\Temp\inputfilename.txt' | ForEach-Object{ Get-ADGroup -Identity $_ -properties mail | select name,mail | sort mail | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\outputfilename.csv' -NoTypeInformation}
```

PowerShell seems to be listing the members for the various groups in an error state in the console and not returning anything to the output file.

Error:

```
Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: '"usernameofusersanitizedfortheinternet","NameofUser (usernameofuser)","NameofADGroup"' under: 'DC=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX'.
At line:1 char:56
+ ... ' | ForEach-Object{ Get-ADGroup -Identity $_ -properties mail | selec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: ("usernameofuser","Nameofuser..."ADGroupName":ADGroup) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

Any thoughts?  I can get this to work as a simple script without the loop.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: One problem you have is your usage of `ForEach-Object` and `Export-Csv`. Every time `ForEach-Object` gets one of your group's information and writes it to the csv file, it overwrites the previous groups information so you only end up with info from the last group processed. You can use the `-Append` parameter with `Export-Csv` to end up with all the data.

Comment: The other (bigger) problem is that you are obviously not feeding it a plain .txt file with group names. You should look at your file and make sure it is only group names, because it looks like a csv file. Read the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer-answer, but it's too long to put in a comment. Just some basic advice on troubleshooting, because this is a classic problem when you try and ram everything thru the pipeline - you don't know where is going long.

First off, I'd say @Dusty Vargas has the correct diagnosis - your input file is a csv rather than a simple list of group names.

But let's unravel what you're actually doing and break it down into distinct operations. We can do that by formatting your pipeline into a scriptblock and storing each component into separate variables for analysis.

```
$groups = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\inputfilename.txt'
$results = ForEach ($g in $groups) { 
    Get-ADGroup -Identity $g -properties mail | select name,mail 
}
$results | sort mail | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\outputfilename.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Now we can break it down.

Once you've imported your group file, check the first item by running `$groups[0]`

If it's anything other than the simple name of a group, there's problem 1. It looks like you'll have a string full of quotes and commas, which I hope is not your group naming standard.

If that first line looks like a header row, great. Either import it again by changing your `Get-content` to `import-csv`, or just convert your imported file object with `ConvertFrom-CSV`.

If it's actual data, no header, you can either edit the text file to put one in, or do `Import-Csv <file> -Header 'a','b','name','d'` (whatever you want).

Once you've got `$groups` imported properly, check your input again. Assuming it's a csv with the group name in the `name` field, you can check the value similar to before:

```
$group[0].name
```

That should look like something you can search with in AD.  If not, simply output `$group[0]` again - if it's from a csv, you'll see the field names and values, and be able to select the field name that has the correct data.

Once you have the right field, to simulate what the `Foreach` will do, can set the index variable `$g` to the above, and run the script commands inside the loop.

```
$g = $groups[0]
Get-ADGroup -Identity $g.name -properties mail | select name,mail
```

Hopefully that'll get you an AD group result with the two required properties.

From there, you can run the whole thing, or run the `Foreach` block and check your `$results` by outputting the whole thing or just the first line as done previously.

There are many ways to do these kinds of steps, but I always find if I'm having trouble with a pipeline, breaking it all down, storing the inputs and results in specific variables, and setting a specific index variable, rather than using  `$_` all the time, can help identify where something is going wrong.

Also, if your AD results are fine and you're having trouble with sorting or exporting, you don't need to run the AD query over and over while troubleshooting, since `$results` has stored that data for you.